# I cannot user to direct to another page in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on an anime project and using react-router first time. My problem is that I cannot redirect the user to another page that has anime details.

This is the main component that has anime images and their titles. When the user clicked the image, it has to direct to the anime details component which I cannot do it.

```
 <Container>
      <Row>
        {animes.map((data) => (
          <Col key={data.mal_id} sm={4}>
            <Link to="/anime-details/:mal_id">
              <Image
                src={data.images.jpg.large_image_url}
                alt={`This is ${data.title}`}
                style={{ height: "350px" }}
                className="mt-4"
                rounded
              />
            </Link>
            <p
              style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "1.15rem" }}
              className="mt-2">
              {data.title}
            </p>
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </Container>
```

This is the router in the index.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Main />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "anime-details/:mal_id",
        element: <AnimeDetails />,
        loader: async ({ request, params }) => {
          return axios(`/anime-details/${params.mal_id}`, {
            signal: request.signal,
          })
        },
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

Finally, this is the anime details page

```
import React from "react"

function AnimeDetails() {
  return <div>Anime Details</div>
}

export default AnimeDetails
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

From what I can tell the link target path you are trying to use is a bit malformed.

```
<Link to="/anime-details/:mal_id">
  ...
</Link>
```

This is linking to a literal path string `"/anime-details/:mal_id"` and so when the navigation action is effected the user is navigated to `"/anime-details/:mal_id"` where the `mal_id` route path param will have the literal value `":mal_id"` instead of an actual id value what was being mapped over.

## Solution

Inject the `animes` array data element's `mal_id` property into the target path string when mapping.

```
<Link to={`/anime-details/${data.mal_id}`}>
  ...
</Link>
```

Example:

```
<Container>
  <Row>
    {animes.map((data) => (
      <Col key={data.mal_id} sm={4}>
        <Link to={`/anime-details/${data.mal_id}`}>
          <Image
            src={data.images.jpg.large_image_url}
            alt={`This is ${data.title}`}
            style={{ height: "350px" }}
            className="mt-4"
            rounded
          />
        </Link>
        <p
          style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "1.15rem" }}
          className="mt-2">
          {data.title}
        </p>
      </Col>
    ))}
  </Row>
</Container>
```

[image: Edit i-cannot-user-to-direct-to-another-page-in-react-router]

Comment: It does not work :(

Comment: But, i can see the mal_id in the url

Comment: @Hyperienn I see. It *should* work. Perhaps you have an issue elsewhere that is also preventing the code from working as expected. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: This is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-minsky-b2yopf

Comment: @Hyperienn The code is working as expected in your linked sandbox so it's not clear what issue you see on your end locally.

Comment: The problem is when you click the image, it does not direct to anime details page as it is in the sandbox

Comment: @Hyperienn I don't understand, the sandbox navigates to the correct URL path and I  see the `AnimeDetails` component rendered. Are you saying the sandbox isn't a reproducible example? I noticed the sandbox code was using the regular `BrowserRouter` instead of the `createBrowserRouter` data API router. Could *that* why it's running differently?

Comment: Should i use createBrowserRouter

Comment: `createBrowserRouter` was just introduced in `react-router-dom@6.4.0` but either it or the older `BrowserRouter` way *should* work.

Comment: but, why doesn't work? I cannot see the anime details page both locally and in sandbox

Comment: @Hyperienn Look at the bottom of the page, after all the mapped links/images, the `AnimeDetails` component is rendered by the `Route` you are rendering after all the link content. After you click one of the links you'll see the text `"Anime Details XX"` where "XX" is the id value from the route path parameter.

Comment: Oh, I saw. But the main issue for me is how to show Anime Details in a new page?

Comment: @Hyperienn You already are. It sounds like you ***don't*** want the `animes.map` to be rendered unconditionally, like you also want *that* list of links to be on it's own page. Does this sound correct? If so I can fork your sandbox and provide an edited version that does that.

Comment: It would be great if you fork

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248219/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-hyperienn).

Answer (score -1):

in my opinion you better to use react-router-dom to navigate some page.

```js
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar () {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  
  function toDetailAnime(){
  navigate('/DetailAnime')
  }
  
  return (
  <div className="navbar">
      <h1>Anime</h1>
      <ul>
        <li className="navbar-item">
        <a href="/DetailAnime" onClick={toDetailAnime}>
          Detail Anime 
        </a>
        </li>
        <li className="navbar-item">
        <a href="/DetailAnime1" onClick={toDetailAnime1}>
          Pokemon
        </a>
        </li>
)
}

export default Navbar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```